# Django - too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a custom backend where an user uses a private key and a secret key to view an API endpoint that i made uing Django Rest Framework. I already know this isn't the best in terms of security, but since the endpoint is only for viewing data (it only has the GET method) it's not a big deal here.

Here is my code:

```
class TokenMiddleware(AuthenticationMiddleware):
    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            token = request.GET[TOKEN_QUERY_PUBLIC]
            secret = request.GET[TOKEN_QUERY_SECRET]
        except KeyError:
            raise ValidationError(detail="Missing parameter in auth")

        user = auth.authenticate(request, token=token, secret=secret)
        if user:
            # The token is valid. Save the user to the request and session.
            request.user = user
            auth.login(request, user)
        else:
            raise ValidationError(detail="AUTH FAILED")

class TokenBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, token=None, secret=None):
        if not token:
            return None

        try:
            publicQuery = User.objects.get(api_keys__public=token)
            if publicQuery != None:
                privateQuery = Api_keys.objects.get(public=token, secret=secret)
                if privateQuery.secret == secret:
                    return User.objects.get(username=publicQuery)
                else:
                    return None
            else:
                return None
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            # A user with that token does not exist
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

And here is the `Api_keys` model:

```
class Api_keys(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    public = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    secret = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

The problem with this code is that every time i try to authenticate, i get the following error:

```
too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

More details:

```
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\request.py", line 220, in user
  self._authenticate()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\request.py", line 380, in _authenticate
  self.user, self.auth = user_auth_tuple
```

My imports:

```
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.middleware import AuthenticationMiddleware
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
from api.models import Api_keys
```

The problem should be after line `auth.login(request, user)`, until there i can see that a valid user is being returned. Any kind of help is appreciated!

Comment: "Too many values to unpack" Exception, That exception means that you are trying to unpack a tuple, but the tuple has too many values with respect to the number of target variables , your target and source tuple is not same

Comment: Check https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#example.  DRF auth backends are different from the common django `AUTH_BACKENDS`. They are supposed to return a user/token pair, not just the user!

Comment: Thank you a lot! So in this case what do i need to pass to auth.login?

Comment: @Underoos The problem is that if i don't pass request to authenticate, authenticate won't execute

Comment: Looks like you are confusing `django's authenticate()` with `djangorest's authenticate()`. Can you please post the imports as well

Comment: @Underoos Just added my imports, i'm going to add the whole trace too

Comment: @Underoos No need, i think the problem was that i was importing from Django and not Django Rest

Comment: So, Is the issue resolved now?

Comment: Yes, seems solved